# Error when using to_timestamp in node-postgres insert statement

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using node-postgres and attempting to use to_timestamp and receive the error:

`ReferenceError: to_timestamp is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
let sDate = format(parseISO(myStartDate),'dd/MM/yyyy')
let sTime = format(parseISO(myStartTime), 'HH:mm:ss')
let sDateTime = `${sDate} ${sTime}`
let eDate = format(parseISO(myEndDate),'dd/MM/yyyy')
let eTime = format(parseISO(MyEndTime), 'HH:mm:ss')
let eDateTime = `${eDate} ${eTime}`

console.log(sDate, sTime, sDateTime)
console.log(eDate, eTime, eDateTime)

data = await pool.query(        
      "INSERT INTO my_table (window_start, window_end ) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING data_id",
          [ to_timestamp(sDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_timestamp(eDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ]
    );
```

Here is my console output:

```
25/05/2021 19:56:40 25/05/2021 19:56:40
25/05/2021 19:56:40 25/05/2021 19:56:40
```

but then errors with `ReferenceError: to_timestamp is not defined`

Please note that my table columns for both window_start and window_end are of type `timestamp`

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are not interpolated into the SQL statement, but the `to_timestamp` function is executed in Javascript, which causes the error.

Use something like

```
data = await pool.query(        
      "INSERT INTO my_table (window_start, window_end) VALUES (to_timestamp($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_timestamp($2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') RETURNING data_id",
          [ sDateTime, eDateTime ]
    );
```